# Jquery custom attribute access

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a div present in my js file

```
<div id="myid" data="mydata"></div>
```

when i try to access custom attribute data with pure javascript

```
var data  =  document.getElementById('myid').getAttribute('data');
```

jquery alone

```
 var data = $("#"+myid).attr('data');
```

above both mwthods are working properly but when i try to used the both jquery and javascript

```
var data = $("#"+myid).getAtrribute("data");
```

then is is giving error? but didn't able to get the reason ? can anyone explain please?

Comment: Really, you're suprised it doesn't work when you use a native javascript method on a jQuery object? Why would you even do that ?

Comment: i know its not appropriate but i was just keen to know the reason why this is not working.

Comment: FYI even completly unrelevant to issue, `data` isn't valid attribute for DIV element

Comment: It's not working because a jQuery object has no `getAttribute` property, it has it's own set of properties and methods, that are not at all related to what properties and methods a native DOM node would have.

Answer (score 4):

You are applying a dom method to a jquery object which causes error instead jquery has a method to convert the selector to the dom element `.get()`:

```
$("#"+myid).get(0).getAtrribute("data");
```

```js
alert($('#myid').get(0).getAttribute('data'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myid" data="mydata"></div>
```

As you are using a `data` attribute then better to use `data-*` attribute and jQuery has a method to get it with `.data()` method:

```
<div id="myid" data-mydata="CustomisedData"></div>
```

then in the jQuery:

```
$('#myid').data('mydata'); // will give you "CustomisedData"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$("#"+myid)` is a jQuery instance, not HTML Element object. So you can't use DOM methods on some arbitrary object.

jQuery instance object is an array-like collection of DOM elements. It means that you can extract individual DOM element from it by index if you really need. So in your case you could do this:

```
$("#" + myid)[0].getAtrribute("data");
```

jQuery also offers dedicated method for it [`$.fn.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$("#" + myid).get(0).getAtrribute("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var data = $("#"+myid)[0].getAtrribute("data");
```

Because to use javascript code, you need to use DOM object but jQuery uses array-like collection object.